# Android widget, show an option list after widget being positioned

Tags: android, widget, android-widget

my widget must show different information depending a selected city.
So i'm looking for a right way to display a list after widget being positioned in home.
I'm trying to use the onEnabled() method but on my device (Nexus 7) the option list is displayed when i tap a widget on a widget list and not after it being added on home.
thank you for any help or suggestion
Michele

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at **Creating an App Widget Configuration Activity** part of [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You want to configure your widget before showing it. So, you must declare a configuration activity:

```
<activity android:name=".ExampleAppWidgetConfigurationActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

and add configure property to your  tag

```
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    ...
    android:configure="com.example.android.ExampleAppWidgetConfigurationActivity"
    ... >
</appwidget-provider>
```

It will open this activity whenever user picks up widget and finally you can send your data back to be shown on your widget:

```
val resultValue = Intent().putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId)
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultValue)
finish()
```

read more here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/configuration